# invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression. It should be an element

Tags: javascript, cucumber, gherkin

I am writing automation test in selenium with javascript steps. In the test I want to check if TEXT3 equals TEXT3

HTML code of the website:

```
<div _ngcontent-c35="" class="content">
       <p>
          TEXT1
           <u>
             <strong>TEXT2</strong>
           </u> 
           TEXT3
         </p>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
this.Then(/^also "([^"]*)" as loanPurposeInfoDialogLabel03 is displayed$/, function (fieldValue, next) {
    var fieldText = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content']/p/text()[2]"));
     fieldText.getText().then(getFieldValue => {
      assert.equal(getFieldValue, fieldValue, next, 'Expected value of loanPurposeInfoDialogLabel03 (Text) to be: ' + fieldValue);
    }, next);
  });
```

Javascript code does not work in case I use /text() in XPATH

```
//div[@class='content']/p/text()[2]
```

I get error:

```
InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class='content']/p/text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are giving `text()` function inside of xpath, please try following code :

```
var fieldText = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content']/p/text[2]"));
```

Comment: Sorry, but it did not work.   `code   NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='content']/p/text[1]"}
       (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)` And if I type xpath above into console of google chrome it does not found text xpath whitout **()**

Comment: What happens when you just use "//div[@class='content']/p" this. it can get all text inside.

Comment: If I use "//div[@class='content']/p"  value is TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3 so it is not necesery to create step for TEXT3 Thanks :)

Comment: So that means there is no 3 elements, there is only one element with styling.

Answer (score 0):

If I use xpath

```
"//div[@class='content']/p"
```

value is TEXT1 TEXT2 TEXT3, so it is not necesery to create step for TEXT3

Thanks to Selçuk Ayhan :)